# Module 'lokijs' is not available

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new in ionic I want to use offline data storage in my app. for that I use lokiJS in my ionic app. 
I used "bower install lokijs --save" for add js.

but when I add lokijs dependency in my app.module like

```
 angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'lokijs'])
```

then it show error like below:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module lokijs due    to:                   
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'lokijs' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it."
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Are you importing module definition *.js file properly ?

Comment: yes @xwid and I follow  link step by step
http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-lokijs-for-local-storage-in-your-ionic-app/